# Линейное наследование шаблонных классов

Tags: c++, c++14

Что-то в голову все не придет как сделать линейное наследование классов (Например А->B->C->D) так, что бы можно было бы их менять местами в любой последовательности.

Псевдо код (**Не рабочий**):

```
template <typename Impl>
struct Base {};

template <template <typename> Impl, typename Tag>
struct Base <Impl<Tag>> {};

template <typename Impl, template <typename...> typename ... Basics>
struct A{};

template <template <typename> typename Impl, typename Tag, template <typename...> typename Base, template <typename...> typename ... Basics>
struct A <Impl<Tag>, Base, Basics...> : public Base<Impl<Tag>, Basics ...>{};

template <typename Impl, template <typename...> typename ... Basics>
struct B{};

template <template <typename> typename Impl, typename Tag, template <typename...> typename Base, template <typename...> typename ... Basics>
struct B <Impl<Tag>, Base, Basics...> : public Base<Impl<Tag>, Basics ...>{};

template <typename Tag>
struct  C
    :
        public B<С<Tag>, A, Base>
{};
```

Хотя я считал, что это должно срабоать, но нет. В приведенном выше примере ожидалось *C->B->A->Base*.

**Предположение:** Есть вариант, что в специализациям классав `А` и `В`  последний template pack принимает только шаблоны, которые в свою очередь принимать только полные типы.

**Дополнение:** Есть иерархия статического полиморфизма, тобиш CRTP. Мне нужно составить иерархию, например, А наследует В, В наследует С, С наследует базовый CRTP. Через шаблонные функции можно вызывать любой класс из этой иерархии. Нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог составить любой класса который наследует любую цепочку, которая не противоречит базовому CRTP (Тобиш я мог вызывать методы этого класса). Т.Е. есть 3 класса А, В и С, которые реализуют контракт CRTP и я мог составить класс D, который в любой последовательности может наследовать эти классы, с условием, что самый конечный - это CRTP база. Пример: D->A-Base, D->C->B->Base и так далее.

Более подробный пример Без конструкторов, только класс `A` (По аналогии класс `B`, `C` и так далее. И без других сладостей):

```
template <typename Impl>
template Base
{
protected:
     template <typename Implementation>
     struct Accessor : public Implementation
     { 
          template <typename SomeSpec, typename ... Args>
          static decltype(auto) some_spec(Implement* impl, SomeSpec&& some_spec, Args&& ... args)
          {
              return ::std::invoke(&Implement::some_spec_impl, impl, ::std::forward<SomeSpec>(some_spec), ::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
          }
     };
 private:

 using Access = Accessor<Impl>;

 public:
     template <typename ... Args>
     decltype(auto) some_spec(Args&& ... args) 
     {
         return Access::some_spec(static_cast<Impl*>(this), ::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
     }
};

template <typename Impl>
struct Base_spec{};

template <template <typename> class Impl, typename Tag>
struct Base_spec<Impl<Tag>> : public Base<Impl<Tag>> {

protected:

template <typename Impl>
using Accessor = typename Base<Impl<Tag>>:: template Accessor<Impl>;

protected:
    decltype(auto) some_spec_impl(Some_spec spec)
    {
        // work and return something
    }
};



template <typename Impl>
struct A : public Base_spec<Impl>
{
private:

template <typename Impl>
using Accessor = typename Base_spec<Impl>:: template Accessor<Impl>;

using Access = Accessor<Base_spec<Impl>>;

protected:
    decltype(auto) some_spec_impl(Some_spec spec)
    {
        // some work
        return Access::some_spec(static_cast<Base_spec<Impl>*>(this), spec);
    }
}
```

Соответственно хотелось дать возможность наследовать не только от отдельных классов `А`, который реализует свою функциональность, `B`, который реализует свою и наследует `A`. А, например, функциональность только из `B`. Я не прошу сделать, только указать ошибки в первом примере, использую как пример иерархию из второй.

**Сейчас же классы последовательно наследуются: D->C->B->A->Base**, что хотелось бы исключить.

Comment: `std::tuple`, Не

Comment: Что-то я ничего не понял по псевдокоду. Вы хотите написать что-то вроде вот этого: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_XUnLs ? И если не секрет, зачем вам это? Из академического интереса спрашиваете? :)

Comment: @VTT, попробовать через `tuple`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, дополнил.

Comment: Мне как-то по этой лапше из шаблонов ничего непонятно, уж извините. :/ Вот я скинул короткий кусок кода; чем он отличается от того, что вам нужно (кроме отсутствия CRTP-базы на конце иерархии)? Вообще, какой шаблонный параметр должен передаваться в CRTP-базу: первый класс в иерархии, или последний (который напрямую наследуется от базы)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я уже понял свой недочёт. Так как будет передаваться первый класс в иерархии, то можно сделать короче чем я предполагал. Все равно можете оформить как ответ, если хотите.

Comment: Пожалуй не буду. То есть вопрос исчерпан, или еще нет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, исчерпан.